# Connect UIButton iBOutlet to .h in NIB

Tags: ios

Sorry for my ignorance, but I have always used storyboards and never nibs. I have a nib file and I added a UIButton. Hoe can I link this button to the .h file related to that nib? In storyboard I would ctrl drag the blue line to the .h file and the property would be added...

Comment: this should work in a xib too. Make sure that you have set the correct class of your xib objects.

Answer (score 1):

It is so simple take  IBOutlet   in .h file

```
     IBOutlet UIButton *btnName;
```

And In .xib file see the placeholders and objects and in objects see button right click and black view popup " New referencing outlet" connect with File's Owner see the button object  btnName and connected.

Answer (score 0):

Select your nib file
**cmd + option + return**
This will show your header file as editor window on the right side. Control drag the link to the header file. If you are not able to drag make sure that you set the correct class for the controller. And one more thing some time the editor window doesnt select the file automatically then you need to select it maually

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Find this one and try like this....